# What is the proper way to use pre_get_post?

Tags: pre-get-posts

In an attempt to learn the proper way of using `pre_get_posts`, I came across the example below. As the comment goes, it suggests that the default WordPress query for a given URL should return the relevant information.

```
   // escape if not the main wordpress search query
    if ( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
```

If the aim is to only target the search page, I'm unclear as to why it couldn't/wouldn't be written differently. For example:

```
if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
 // do something
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if ( $query->is_search() ) {
 // do something
}
```

- Why do `OR` `!$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query()`?
- Is `$query->is_main_query() needed`?

My understanding of `$query->is_main_query` is that it affects ALL queries on ALL pages, posts, taxonomies e.g. Category, terms e.g. Category and custom post types.

Comment: It's `pre_get_posts` and not `pre_get_post`, and `$query->is_main_query` is a method/function, so always use `()`, i.e. `$query->is_main_query()`. And we need to call that method if we want to ensure our code is not messing with the main query which runs on page load, or when we want to target that query *only*.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I updated the question.  Could you expand on ` And we need to call that method if we want to ensure our code is not messing with the main query which runs on page load`?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

From your comments, it seemed that you're having a hard time understanding about the WordPress main query and the [`is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) *method* in the `WP_Query` class, so hopefully the following would help clear your doubts:

1. Please check [codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) and learn how WordPress determines what posts or pages to display on a page. The main query is setup in step 4 and there you'll see "*`$wp_query` is an object of class `WP_Query`*".

   That object, however, is a copy of the actual object which holds the main query, and the object's name is `wp_the_query`, i.e.

   ```php
   $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new WP_Query();
   ```
2. So, the `is_main_query` method is used to check whether the query object - that's passed as the 1st parameter to the callbacks/functions hooked on `pre_get_posts` - is the main query object or a custom/secondary query object.

   ```php
   // WordPress runs the pre_get_posts hook like so, where the $this is an instance
   // of the WP_Query class:
   do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );

   // So a callback/function hooked on the pre_get_posts hook like so, will receive
   // the above $this as the first (and the only) parameter:
   function my_pre_get_posts_callback( $query ) {
       // do something here
   }

   // And inside of the above function, you can call the is_main_query METHOD if you
   // need to check whether the $query is for the main query or not:
   if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
       // it's the main query object
   }

   // The above `if` block is equivalent to this, but do not do this and instead, use
   // the is_main_query METHOD when inside a filter or action hook callback which is
   // passed the WP_Query object:
   global $wp_the_query; // access the main query object which should NEVER be modified
   if ( $query === $wp_the_query ) {
       // it's the main query object
   }
   ```
3. See also the **global** function named [`is_main_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query/), which *calls the above class method* and checks if the global variable `$wp_query` (the one mentioned in the above linked article in Codex) is or (still) references the main query object.

   ```php
   // The global is_main_query FUNCTION will always compare the global $wp_query object
   // with the global $wp_the_query object, i.e.
   // This function call:
   if ( is_main_query() ) {
       // it's the main query object
   }

   // is equivalent to, but this is just a demo, so do not do this:
   global $wp_query, $wp_the_query;
   if ( $wp_query === $wp_the_query ) {
       // it's the main query object
   }
   ```

Remember, a global function is a function defined in the global scope and can be called anywhere in PHP, whereas a class method is a function defined inside a class.

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Example Plugin
Version: 0.1
*/

class Example_Plugin {
    public function a_class_method() {
        // do something
    }
}

function a_global_function() {
    // do something
}
```

And you should *read* these, if you haven't:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/#more-information
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

---

### Original Answer

> Is `$query->is_main_query()` needed?

From the `pre_get_posts` documentation:

> #### [Targeting the right query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#targeting-the-right-query)
>
> Be aware of the queries you are changing when using the
> `pre_get_posts`  action. Make use of  [conditional
> tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)
> to target the right query. For example, it's recommended to use the
> the
> [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/)
> conditional to  **not**  change queries in the admin screens. With the
> `$query->is_main_query()`  conditional from the query object you can
> target the main query of a page request. The main query is used by the
> primary  [post
> loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)  that
> displays the main content for a post, page or archive. Without these
> conditionals you could unintentionally be changing the query for
> custom loops in sidebars, footers, or elsewhere.

So that should answer your question, but I'd like to add some additional details:

- `pre_get_posts` runs for all [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) requests and runs on pretty much ***everywhere*** in WordPress, e.g. the front-end/non-admin side of the site, the admin area (`wp-admin`), the REST API and feed requests, and many more including favicon requests (at `/favicon.ico`)!

  So if you're modifying the query arguments such as `posts_per_page` and/or `post_type`, then they will by default be modified for all queries including the main WordPress query which runs automatically on page load before the template is determined.

  Therefore, if for example `post_type` is set to `post`, then the admin pages for managing posts in other post types would always show posts in the `post` type!

  And thus, make sure to target the right query, in order to prevent issues like the above one from happening.

> If the aim is to only target the search page, I'm unclear as to why it
> couldn't/wouldn't be written differently.

As for that `if ( $query->is_search() )`, you can of course do that or use such conditional, but remember that the `$query` could be the main query (the global `$wp_query` object) or a custom instance of the `WP_Query` class, e.g. `$query = new WP_Query( 's=foo' );`, hence you may or may not need to check for the main query, depending on your specific use case or what your code modifies/does.

As for your 1st example, though, which is in example 2 below, that can surely be done, and any of these will work, i.e. the `posts_per_page` is set to `5` only for the main query on the search results pages, e.g. at `https://example.com/?s=keyword`:

- **Example 1:** The `if` block here is used to *exit the function* if the current query is *not* the main query or is *not* a search query.

  ```php
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
      if ( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query() ) {
          return; // do nothing and exit the function
      }

      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  } );
  ```
- **Example 2:** The `if` block here is used to *do something **only if*** the current query **is** the main query and **is** a search query.

  ```php
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
      if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
          $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
      }
  } );
  ```

So the difference is just in how you write the algorithm.

Comment: If the aim is to for example to target the results returns from a search with 5 posts per page, `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );`, why is there a need to include ` $query->is_main_query()`? Isn't ` $query->is_main_query()` intended to determine the relevant template only?

Comment: Whether there is a need to include that or not, it actually depends on you (i.e. the one who wrote the code, and knows what the code is for or what it does). And yes, the main query determines what template to load for the current URL/page (e.g. if the URL is `https://example.com/?s=foo`, then `search.php` is loaded), but `$query->is_main_query()` only checks if the current query object is for the main query. So basically, if you need to check whether that `$query` is the main query, then call the `is_main_query()` method; otherwise, then you don't need to call it. Makes sense?

Comment: And by "*custom instance of the `WP_Query` class*", I was referring to secondary queries which can be done by a theme or plugin, and even WordPress core. See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops) and [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/#more-information) for further details about secondary queries.

Comment: no it isn't clear. Here's what I've understood so far. the main query determines the template for the requested URL. I lost you at `$query->is_main_query() only checks if the current query object is for the main query.` Do you mean that other than loading the right template, it also decides which queries to run for the page? If yes, that means that I would include to include the main query with other conditionals?

Comment: I hope the Update helps? 

Comment: I get that there's the main query and the conditional `is_main_query()`. I'll try asking it another way as I may not have been clear. Why do we need to check if it's the main query or not? What determines that we should check for it along with other conditionals? What are examples of when the main query should be checked and when it shouldn't?

Comment: As for the "why", it's because we want to ensure that we are not *unnecessarily* changing the main query, or if we want to change the main query only, then we want to make sure our code does not change secondary/custom queries that do `new WP_Query` which triggers the `pre_get_posts` action/hook. As for your other questions, you just need to understand what the main query and secondary/custom queries are, and what the `is_main_query` method does, and you'll know when should or should you not check for the main WP query.

Comment: If you want your code to change only the main query on search results pages, e.g. at `https://example.com/?s=hello`, in which case the main query has *a non-empty `s` value*, then you would want to do `if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() )`. But if you want to change all/any search queries including custom ones, e.g. `$my_query = new WP_Query( 's=hello' );`, then you could just do `if ( $query->is_search() )`, i.e. without checking for the main query or `is_admin()`.

Comment: So as for your 2nd question, there is no definitive answer, but if you understand what a conditional does and when/where should it be called, then you'd know when should you or whether you should check for the main query along with other conditionals. And I hope my replies helped, but if not, then maybe you should post another question.